# Design a custom year view with 12 month slots

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Sample View:

[image: SampleView]

I would like to create a custom year view to show the timeline in every month slots. I can use fullcalendar-scheduler with a custom view and define like this:

```
 views: {
   timelineCustom: {
    type: 'timeline',
    buttonText: 'Year View',               
    duration: {year:1},   
    slotDuration: {month:1}
   }
 }
```

However, there is no way to set up a fiscal year view with month start at April 1st and end at March 31st next year. And also, a timeline bar will cover a whole month slot even though an event only starts from the second half of that month.

Comment: What params can be put in "duration" object or "view" object that can control a 3-level timeline (Year/month/day)?

Comment: I found a solution using the newest fullCalendar - see answer below.

Comment: @JoeyYao: Are you able to create this type of scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem - starting the view in April and ending in March of the following year, can be solved using the new "visibleRange" option. This lets you supply start/end dates for the view, relative to the "currentDate" (i.e. the date fullCalendar curently regards as being selected). You also have to set the "dateIncrement" option, to ensure that Next/Previous increment the current date by 1 year.

N.B. This requires fullCalendar 3.3.0 and Scheduler 1.6.0, or later.

```
timelineCustom: {
    type: 'timeline',
    buttonText: 'Year View', 
    dateIncrement: { years: 1 },
    slotDuration: { months: 1 },
    visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
        return {
            start: currentDate.clone().startOf('year').add({ months: 3}),
            end: currentDate.clone().endOf("year").add({ months: 4})
        };
    }
}
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/visibleRange/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/dateIncrement/ for more details

However, your issue where the timeline bar covers a whole month slot even though an event only starts in the second half of a month, is not really solvable in the way you want. The whole point of "slots" is to be the minimum time that an event can be displayed for *in that particular view*. If you want it to be more subtle than that, you would have to define shorter slots. The same thing happens in fullCalendar's default "Month" (non-timeline) view - all events cover a whole day even if they're timed, but you can see the times in the description. I see in your example you have already got the dates of those events displayed in the description, so it should be reasonably clear for your users.

I suggest your users click on the Month View to get a more detailed breakdown with the slot durations more accurately displayed. Either that or you have to compromise and set `slotDuration` to something smaller.

Comment: Yes, I realized that if I need a specific date range, I must use slots by "day". And your solution really helps me out on my first problem. I edit a bit on "end of visibleRange" to make it work (end: currentDate.clone().endOf("year").add({ months: 4})). Thanks a lot!

Comment: great, glad it helped. Thanks for pointing out the mistake with the end date - have amended the answer to reflect that.